# django setUpTestData doesn't run

Tags: django, testing, django-models, django-testing

Here is my test:

```
class FirstTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Car.objects.create(id=10001)

    def findAllCars(self):
        print(list(Car.objects.all()))
```

this gives no errors, and the list is simply printed as [], when clearly it should be [10001]

I know tests aren't supposed to inlude print statements, this is just an easy way to illustrate that for some reason the object in setUpTestData is not being created. How can I get it to make this object?

Comment: You have defined it as class method where are you calling it ?

Comment: that's the problem then, where should I call it? I haven't worked with class methods before

Comment: I'm using this as a reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing#test_structure_overview and I can't see the method being called here, I assumed it was called automatically

Comment: Since you haven't updated your question with models i would assume id field is auto generated so remove `id=10001` and instead use so other field like `Car.objects.create(name='BMW')` if you have name field.

Answer (score 1):

`setUpTestData` is only run, if your test inherits from `APITestCase` but not from `APITransactionTestCase`:

```py
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class ExampleTestCase(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        print("This is setUpTestData")

    def test_something(self):
        print("This is the test")
        self.assertTrue(True)
```